# PEAR::Mail error after installing openssl

Tags: php, email

I've been installing ssl today on my server (debian), works!
But something has changed beside that, now I can't send emails.
This has never been a problem before.

Getting this error:

```
authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: 2.0.0 SMTP server ready)]
```

My code:

```
function sendemail($too, $title, $post){
set_include_path("." . PATH_SEPARATOR . ($UserDir = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) . "/pear/php" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once "Mail.php";

$host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
$username = "no-reply@developerhelp.org";
$password = "****";
$port = "587";
$to = $too;
$email_from = 'DeveloperHelp <no-reply@developerhelp.org>';
$email_subject = "DeveloperHelp: ".$title;
$email_body = $post;
$email_address = "";

$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
}
```

Thanks in adv!

Comment: Just a question, you seem to use PEAR::Mail, not PHPMailer as you tagged your post - are both packages related somehow?

Comment: Oh, you are right ^^ Will edit :) Thanks. They are not related what I know

Comment: You can pass an additional parameter `'debug' => true` to the `Mail::factory()` method, does this give you a verbose error message?

Comment: Yes. I got this: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2nrjbk2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using PHPmailer instead and allowing self signed certificates. Added this lines to PHPMailer:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                    )
                );
```